# How to interpret RMSE of 0 with a lot of features

Tags: regression, overfitting, rms

I have 122 features for a regression problem. Here are some stats on a random forest model using RMSE:

**With no scaling or dimensionality reduction:**

Train RMSE: 0.0

Test RMSE: 0.0

CV RMSE: 0.0

**With scaling and dimensionality reduction to 2 components:**

Train RMSE: 0.03

Test RMSE: 0.01

CV RMSE: 0.03

How can I tell if the model without scaling/dimensionality reduction is overfitting if the RMSE is 0 for all cases? I know you should scale before regression and PCA, but why does that seem to be performing better? Or it is just misleading with the 0s?

Comment: How many cases do you have?

Comment: What is the range of your response variable?  If all your responses values are tiny (e.g. 0.0001-0.0009) the RMSE will also be small.

Comment: @Underminer the range of the response is 0.2064. It can be between 0 and 1.

Comment: @EdM I have 219,737 training points.

Comment: Are the RMSE values on the training set or on a test set?

Comment: @EdM I provided the RMSE for training, test (which is actually the validation set), and from cross validation

Comment: How precisely are you reporting these results? E.g., is "0.0" a *true, exact* zero or would it just mean anything less than 0.05?

Comment: @whuber They are a lot of values x 10^-30. RMSE on validation set is actually 7.3e-06

Comment: It's clear you are able to perfectly predict a lot of cases.  I'd look at variable importance from the Random Forest to figure out what's leading to there perfectly predicted cases.  How many different values for your response variable do you have (or is it truly continuous)?  If the response variable has different levels, did you process the different levels of the response variable in different ways?

Comment: @Underminer Thanks for the response. I'm just thinking about if it's ever okay to not scale before regression and to have many features, because I normally would have scaled and reduced the dimension but it's hard to tell if it's overfitting if it has an RMSE of 0. The distribution the predictions seems to almost exactly match that of the actual values, even though it was on untrained validation set.

Comment: Without seeing the data, it's impossible to say for sure, but I do think it is overfitting and my first guess would be a data issue causing the overfit.  Based on the number of perfectly predicted cases, I'm guessing the response variable isn't truly continuous.  The distribution of response variables would help, along with any information about how the data was collected.